# Issue when rendering childAction to parent view asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem when rendering my ChildAction:

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult ListAll()
    {

        var user_id = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        var client_id = from d in db.Connexions 
                        where d.userId == user_id && d.Action == "Creation"
                        select d.ClientID;
        //var cust_id = (int)client_id;

        var lastClient = from d in db.Clients
                         where d.ClientID == client_id.Max()
                         select d;
        return View(lastClient);
     }
```

And I render it here in my Create Page :

```
  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateOut)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateOut)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateOut)
    </div>
    <p> @{Html.RenderAction("ListAll");} </p> //---- Here
```

I don't know why have an HttpException error with details: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Here is my ListAll partial view and strongly typed using Client model:

```
@model Gestion_restrictions.Models.Client

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.portfolio)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dateIn)
    </th>
   <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.portfolio)
    </td>
```

etc...

Can somebody help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Include the details of the exception

Comment: What is the model definition in the view? (your passing it `IEnumerable<Clients>`)

Comment: Yes there is a problem of type that I pass it say me when I continue to debug that I am trying to pass a DBQuery[Gestion.Models.Client] to Gestion.Models.Client. Because first I think that I have to set a strongly type partial view with Client model but I think it wrong. I am not passing IEnumerable because I just pass one reference of object Client

Comment: No, you are passing `IEnumerable` (thats what `.Where()` does). You need to add `.FirstOrDefault()` to return only one value

Comment: Ok so I have to add .First() after Max() ? because I've tried it it throws an error, so where I have to add it ? thank you

Comment: Try `var lastClient = (from d in db.Clients where d.ClientID == client_id.Max() select d).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: The Max does not pick just one value ?

Comment: Yes it selects one value, but its a **collection** containing that one value, not the value itself

Comment: Ok I've tried it but now I have an error with the var lastClient, it says me that I cannot assign a group of method to implicit typed local variable

Comment: No sorry it works I have forgotten the parenthesis! Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe if you want answer to the question in order to validate your answer

Comment: But it doesn't work yet when I debug the same error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model definition for your view is `Client` but you are passing it `IEnumerable<Client>`. Change the following

```
var lastClient = from d in db.Clients
  where d.ClientID == client_id.Max()
  select d;
```

to

```
var lastClient = (from d in db.Clients
  where d.ClientID == client_id.Max()
  select d).FirstOrDefault(); // or .SingleOrDefault()
return View(lastClient);
```

Comment: Sorry but This error is thrown again The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Client_D1F67343D5BDDB5F8F8CC06C394E225FD60B4801AC2B93F5ADEDA95EAA1FA900', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Gestion_restrictions.Models.Client]'.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the first few lines of the view - in particular `@model....`

Comment: I have edited the question but the same error is thrown at RenderAction("listAll")

Comment: Check if the value of `lastClient` is null.

Comment: I have just checked it with the debugging step by step and it is not null there are values

Comment: and is it type of `Gestion_restrictions.Models.Client`?

Comment: Yes exactly it is written in the column type Gestion_restrictions.Models.Client{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Client_D1F67343.....}

Comment: Excellent it works !!!! It was just my view was first created with strongly typed model Client but List not Empty ! And now it works ! Thank you very much for your help !!!